# Rexster query returns "No such property: v for class: com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph"

Tags: groovy, cassandra, titan, bulbs, rexster

I'm using TitanGraphDB + Cassandra. I'm starting Titan as follows

```
cd titan-cassandra-0.3.1
bin/titan.sh config/titan-server-rexster.xml config/titan-server-cassandra.properties
```

I have a Rexster shell that I can use to communicate to Titan + Cassandra above.

```
cd rexster-console-2.3.0
bin/rexster-console.sh
```

I'm attempting to model a network topology using Titan Graph DB. I want to program the Titan Graph DB from my python program. I'm using bulbs package for that.
I create five types of vertices

```
 - switch
 - port 
 - device
 - flow
 - flow_entry
```

I create edges between vertices that are connected logically. The edges are not labelled.

Let us say I want to test the connectivity between `Vertex A` and `Vertex B`

I have a groovy script is_connected.groovy

```
def isConnected (portA, portB) {
    return portA.both().retain([portB]).hasNext()
}
```

Now from my rexster console

```
g = rexster.getGraph("graph")
==>titangraph[embeddedcassandra:null]
rexster[groovy]> g.V('type', 'flow')    
==>v[116]
==>v[100]
rexster[groovy]> g.V('type', 'flow_entry')
==>v[120]
==>v[104]
```

As you can see above I have two vertices of type flow `v[116]` and `v[100]`

I have two vertices of type `flow_entry` `v[120]` and `v[104]`

I want to check for the connectivity between `v[120]` and `v[116]` for e.g

```
rexster[groovy]> ?e is_connected.groovy       
==>null
rexster[groovy]> is_connected(g.v[116],g.v[120])
==>An error occurred while processing the script for language [groovy]. All transactions across all graphs in the session have been concluded with failure: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: v for class: com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph
```

Either I am doing something very wrong,or I am missing something obvious.It would be great if you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is not valid groovy:

```
is_connected(g.v[116],g.v[120])
```

should be:

```
is_connected(g.v(116),g.v(120))
```

Comment: Note his Gremlin-Groovy script's function definition is Groovy-style camelCase `isConnected()`, but in the Rexster console he's using Python-style snake_case `is_connected()` -- that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up Python syntax with Gremlin-Groovy syntax:

You defined the Groovy script as:

```
def isConnected (portA, portB) {
    return portA.both().retain([portB]).hasNext()
}
```

...so...

```
rexster[groovy]> is_connected(g.v[116], g.v[120])
```

...should be...

```
rexster[groovy]> isConnected(g.v(116), g.v(120))
```